# Making a database in Redis

Tags: database, redis

So I want to make a database on Redis with simple keys and values and I want to visualize it with grafana. So grafana requires me to put the address(redis://) but I have no idea how to get that. I know how to open Redis on my terminal with redis-cli, but no idea how to get a web address for it cause what i have is the port in this form, 127.0.0.1:6379>. I am an extreme noob in both these tools, so some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using this source https://github.com/RedisGrafana/grafana-redis-datasource?

Comment: I saw this, but I wasn't too sure if I could do it without Docker? Would love to know if Docker is necessary for it. Thanks

Comment: Is Grafana running in same server as redis? If yes, 127.0.0.1 should work, otherwise you will have to use the host name of the server where redis is running